# Cross build i386 linux kernel on amd64 host

Tags: kernel, debian, cross-compiling

I am trying to build a i386 Linux kernel deb package on a amd64 Debian host.

Now I am doing this by set `--cross-compile flag`. It does done greate job to the kernel itself. But the problem is kernel tools, which still be compiled as local machine formart. Only changing `HOSTCC` variable cannot solve this problem because of linker mis-match.

I knew `chroot` or `linux32` environment will work. But, are they the only ways?  There should be another solution because someone may want to build a arm kernel.

PS: Here is the command I am using:

```
CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=8 DEB_HOST_ARCH=i386 MAKEFLAGS="HOSTCC=/home/csl/bin/i486-linux-gnu-gcc"\
make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --arch i386 --cross-compile /home/csl/bin/i486-linux-gnu- --append-to-version=-liquorix-csl binary-arch \
> >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it like this:

1. sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
2. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs gcc-multilib
3. make i386_defconfig
4. make ARCH=i386 -j5 deb-pkg

I haven't got time to explore if ia32-libs where really needed. But I want to point that make-kpkg is deprecated, as explained in the debian book.

Comment: Yes, but make-kpkg is deprecated. See the [Debian Linux Kernel Handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-building)

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it now like this:

```
CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=6 DEB_HOST_ARCH=i386 setarch i386 make-kpkg --initrd --arch i386 binary-arch
```

I didn't see any complain about make-kpkg in the debian book, so can you show your reference in the debian book?

I find the real problem is the kernel tools contained in the `scripts` dir must be compiled as native formats, which may assistant kernel building. But this tools cannot be reused when doing DKMS, this is simply because DKMS conflicts quitely with cross-compile. I will hack the broken cross-builded kernel manualy.